# How to use a variable instead of Hard-Coding in v lookup

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

In the below Vllokup function.
I want to use a variable instead of using hard-coded value as "No Category"

=IF( ISNA( VLOOKUP(Param)),"No Category", IF(LEN(VLOOKUP(Param)) =0,"", VLOOKUP(Param) ))

I tried like the following way , unfortunately i can't make it.

=IF( ISNA( VLOOKUP(Param)),**" & VarCategory & ",** IF(LEN(VLOOKUP(Param)) =0,"", VLOOKUP(Param) ))

Many Thanks

Comment: You can use a cell reference instead of VarCategory right?

Comment: Are you trying to build this formula in vba? or directly in an excel cell? Also `VLOOKUP(Param)` is not a valid call of `VLOOKUP`: you need more arguments

Comment: Are you writing that in VBA? Please post more of your code. Are you NOT using VBA? Then please don't tag with VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cell in your spreadsheet as a search box. For example, say you pick cell A1 as the box that can contain whatever you type into it. Your formula can then say:

```
=IF( ISNA( VLOOKUP(Param)), A1 , IF(LEN(VLOOKUP(Param)) =0,"", VLOOKUP(Param) ))
```

Now your `VLOOKUP` is no longer hard coded. It will look based on whatever is in cell A1.